# How to partially build a Python package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have some private Python packages that have common functionalities, I would like to include only the private packages from the dependencies when building another Python package that depends on them, so when installing the built package pip would not try to search for the local private packages.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I don't understand the question and don't know how to answer it. I think rephrasing, more details, clarifications are needed.

Comment: I will write a custom `setup.py` showing what I mean and add to the question

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/RamiAwar/packr

Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: @RamiAwar I found [vendoring](https://github.com/pradyunsg/vendoring) to be the best solution, pip has no builtin support for what I wanted.

Comment: What does vendoring do? Didn't get it @hldev

Comment: @RamiAwar it copies source code of the packages you want to vendor into the project, so instead of trying to change the builder I just copy the dependency into the project and rewrite all imports to refer to the local copy.

Comment: so if I want to blundle "foo" dependency I copy its source into `_vendor` subpackage of my project and rewrite `import foo.bar` as `import _vendor.foo.bar`.

Comment: Oh yeah that takes things one step further. So vendoring is actually downloading the source when it's available, and then rewriting the imports to be local?

Still a lot of bloat. Technically even more bloat this way since you're downloading all the source and then building.

But if I could incorporate this into Packr then you'd be able to remove all parts of the source that aren't used.